# How to build table from two tables, one with useless unique identifier (WordPress wp_usermeta table)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Use case background**: I'm using a WordPress site to manage memberships, and the ID Card software on my PC will connect to a table to generate its information. It can connect to *only* one table.

**Goal**: I need a table called "id_card" that contains the columns (member_number, first_name, last_name, exp_date), and it's populated with users that have been modified within the last month ("membership" table has a column titled "moddate" that I can use as the criteria).

**Challenge 1**: I need to pull exp_date from table "membership" and the other values -- member_number, first_name, last_name -- all come from a table called "wp_usermeta" (a default table for WordPress).  Both source tables contain user_id to associate the information to the same user account.  I believe this requires some kind of `LEFT JOIN`, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

**Challenge 2**: the bigger challenge: wp_usermeta table contains all the different user attributes in ROWS instead of COLUMNS.  So the columns are titled "user_id, meta_key, meta_value" and there might be 30 rows for a single user. If I want to SELECT user 49's first name, it looks something like this:

`SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id=49 AND meta_key='first_name'`

**Question**: How do I write this query so it will `INSERT INTO` the table "id_card" the values from the two tables, using the user_id to keep it all lined up, especially when I can't use *solely* the user_id as a unique identifier (i.e. the only way I know to narrow it down to someone's first name is use *both* their user_id and the meta_key) in the wp_usermeta table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a major problem with your wanting to copy data. If the user changes their data then your copy will be out of date. If you look at the wp_users table there is a ID field. This points to the relevant entries in the wp_usermeta table (user_id)

```
SELECT `wp_users`.*
    , `wp_usermeta`.*
FROM `wp_users`
    INNER JOIN `wp_usermeta` ON (`wp_users`.`ID` = `wp_usermeta`.`user_id`)
WHERE ID=1;
```

Now this will return multiple rows. If you want a single record then you'll need to do

```
SELECT`wp_users`.*
    , (SELECT meta_key FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key='wp_user_level' AND user_id=1) AS user_level
    , (SELECT meta_key FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key='show_syntax_highlighting' AND user_id=1) AS syntax_highlighting
FROM `wp_users`
 WHERE ID=1;
```

Just repeat the subquery statements for as much info that you want to return. The subquery can only return a single value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The plan is that I'll enter in a date and click "update" on an HTML form, which will post to a PHP file which uses the `mysqli_query()` function to update that database (following a truncation command to start with a blank table).  My hope is that this will create a "current" table to be used within 1 hour or so.  The person printing cards will perform this "update," then use the ID software to print the entire table since it's just those who have been updated since the desired "moddate" value.

Comment: OK, I understand. You will still need to use the above example to get the data out of the wordpress tables then copy this data into your working table.

Comment: I'm a step closer, but I'm getting 1600 rows per user.  There are only 37 users who meet the `WHERE` criteria.  It's giving me the info I want, and it's in the correct spot, but it's still wrong.  I can't figure out why/where it's looping so much.  Here's a screenshot of the code being used:  https://ibb.co/7trVTMb Here's a screenshot of the database result: https://ibb.co/RYKr9xC.

Comment: Got it working.  Someone else pointed out that I added a second table in `FROM` which was the culprit.  Thank you for the solution, Jeff.